# Can't execute compiled program: Exec format error

Tags: ftp, c++

First, this has nothing to do with 64bit-32bit mismatch, file extensions, nor permissions.

I compiled a program (C++ 11) in a non-Ubuntu distro, and I uploaded it onto an Ubuntu Server (64 bit) with FTP.
There I get the error defined in the title:

```
Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The strange thing is that my previous version (that I compiled a month ago, and that I copied on a windows PC), doesn't work either when I upload it from my Linux, but runs if I upload it from my windows. The file is exactly the same.

Is this an FTP error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which is your FTP program? And what is the output of `file /path/to/program` on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: FileZilla (both windows and on linux the same version) and as output I got this:  pulse: `ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), too many program header sections (2573)`

Comment: If you are compiling on a non-Ubuntu system it is VERY likely you are not going to get the correct libraries linked to the program, unless you're compiling a static binary file.  You should always compile on an environment that you expect to deploy to, rather than compile on a different distro/environment and expect it to just work.

Comment: But why does my old version works? I didn't change the libraries. That's why it keeps bugging me...

Comment: Has nothing to do with FTP upload failing - it's more likely that you should not be building things on Windows you plan on deploying on Ubuntu (and vice versa unless you're configured to do Windows crosscompiliation on Ubuntu)

Comment: I compiled all versions on Linux, my windows just served as a sort of backup.

Comment: @Antony could you check the FTP upload mode for both machines Binary or ASCII ? It could be Auto, I would suggest set it to BIN and upload new copy, see if it works. For libraries, you can use `ldd` to check availability of linked ones.

Comment: Impossible to say with what little information you posted. Perhaps the file is corrupt, perhaps there is a problem with dependencies, who knows. You often can compile a program on Ubuntu X and expect it to run on Windows, Ubuntu Y , or Fedora, etc. Post the source code or compile it on Ubuntu and post any errors.

Comment: @Sneetsher Thank you soo much, changing the transfer type to bin helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the FTP transfer mode!

**ASCII** may not work as supposed in some ftp client/server combination on different OS's.

So **Binary** mode should be used with binary file formats and Unicode text files too to confirm integrity of data. In this mode, the data are copied bit-to-bit, it constructs same exact copy. Reference: [FTP Upload Corrupting PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/693971/ftp-upload-corrupting-pdf)

**Auto** may not work well for some clients because executable programs do not have to be with specific extension in Linux.