# Exec format error, transferring file with filezilla

Tags: filezilla, golang

I have a compiled file written with golang, if I transfer the file to another PC with a usb driver, and add the permission with sudo chmod +x myfile, it runs perfectly, but when I transferr the file with filezilla and do the same process, it says: can not execute binary fil: exec format error, Why is that?

Comment: Maybe related: [Can't execute compiled program: Exec format error](https://askubuntu.com/a/732133/178692)

Comment: That was it thank you. I change the format to binary and it worked.